# Is this a different way of expressing set membership?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following expression:

$$
y=2k \ \text{for} \ k=1,2,...,m
$$

The same as this one?

$$
y=2k \ \text{for} \ k \in \{1,2,...,m\}
$$

Comment: The first one and second one are both slight abuses of notation that mean $y\in\{2k\mid k\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\}$

Comment: Is there a way of expressing them using the $=$ sign?

Comment: I just gave you the formal way of expressing it, but honestly, people abuse notation in math all the time in the name of laziness/readability, so I guess this is fine.

Comment: For instance, I could contend that if @DonThousand wanted to use properly the set-builder notation he should write $\{n\in\Bbb Z\,:\, \exists k\in \{1,2,\cdots, m\},\, n=2k\}$, instead of the "range-builder" notation $\{f(k)\,:\, k\in A\}$. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Gae.S. I agree, even I wasn't as pedantic as I could have been.